# Im trying to create the regular expression to include the text and not the href

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that will include the the text in the HTML but not the the web address.

This is the code:

```
<h2 class="story-heading"><a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20171012234502/https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/12/us/politics/trump-obamacare-executive-order-health-insurance.html">Trump Allows for Cheaper, Less Regulated Health Plans</a></h2>
```

I tried doing the regular expression:
`<h2 class="story-heading">(.*?)</a></h2>`

But I'm confused on how I would remove the href part of that line as well to only include the text? So I need it to only return "Trump Allows for Cheaper, Less Regulated Health Plans"

Comment: You'd be better off using one of the available html parsers to parse the html, then traverse the result rather than trying to decode it manually.

Comment: We have to use a regular expression tester given to us. Is there any way to do this purely as a regular expression?

Comment: You can approximate it with a regular expression, but it probably won't handle all cases.

Comment: <.*>(.*)<\/a><\/h2> this regex is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression should do what you want

```
<h2 class="story-heading"><a.*?>(.*?)<\/a><\/h2>
```

The only difference between this and your initial attempt is that it stops at the closing ">" and then captures from there to the next "<".

This should work as long as the text you're looking for is between the 'a' tags. I don't know how efficient this is though.

EDIT: Further explanation as requested:

First we match the story header

```
<h2 class="story-heading">
```

Then match the opening of the link tag, followed by any characters in the link until we find the closing of that tag.

```
<a.*?>
```

Then we capture any characters we can, this will be the title we're looking for

```
(.*?)
```

Until we find the opening of corresponding link tag and the header tag

```
<\/a><\/h2>
```

Note: the backslashes there may not be necessary for what you're using, I added them because they were necessary in the tool I was using, which might also help you understand if my explanation is inadequate: [Online regex tester with explanations](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Would you please be able to explain the seperate parts of that so that I can reuse/edit the code for other instances?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = '<h2 class="story-heading"><a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20171012234502/https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/12/us/politics/trump obamacare-executive-order-health-insurance.html">Trump Allows for Cheaper, Less Regulated Health Plans</a></h2>'
final_data = re.findall('>([a-zA-Z,\s]+)</a></h2>', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'Trump Allows for Cheaper, Less Regulated Health Plans'
```